# list items among each other jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a litte chat application. The list items becomes created by a while loop. Now messages are regularly among each other but in this case they are in the same line until the sites width then a break become created. How should I edit the css or add classes that the list items are among each other?

```
<div style="height:100%; width:100%" data-role="content" id="container">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <div style="width:100%" id="chatOutput">
    <li style="float: right; ;background-color:white;border-radius: 1em;" class="chatPost"><p class="stringSender"></p><p class="stringText">fd</p><p style="font-size:80%" class="stringTime">15:04:03</p></li>
    <li style="float: right; ;background-color:white;border-radius: 1em;" class="chatPost"><p class="stringSender"></p><p class="stringText">lala</p><p style="font-size:80%" class="stringTime">10:19:03</p></li>
        </div>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use

```
clear : both;
```